# should I rebuild the project after pulling the changes from VCS?

Tags: android-studio

When I pull the changes from VCS (I am working on a team project), do I have to rebuild the project or is this done automatically?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling the changes will not cause a rebuild. If the pull operation has caused any `.gradle` files to change, AS will prompt you to re-sync them which might cause the project to be rebuilt.

If you want to see whether the project update results in any errors, you should rebuild manually.

**Note**: without rebuilding, you will be able to see some kinds of errors (syntax errors, paths not found etc.) *if you actually open the file containing them*. Some other errors (unresolved internal dependencies etc.) can only be seen while building the project.

To answer the actual question: you should rebuild (and run if possible) the project after an update if you want to make sure the changes do not cause any (obvious) issues.